# Expect Object but get String when parsing JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to parse a simple JSON string using jQuery

```
var parsedJSON = $.parseJSON('{"graph_data": "{}"}');
```

I would expect typeof(parsedJSON.graph_data) to be an Object but instead it is returning string.  What is the correct way to return an Object?

Comment: maybe with : `JSON.parse()`

Comment: You're telling it it's a string. `"{}"` should be `{}`

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Data_types.2C_syntax_and_example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be like

```js
var parsedJSON = $.parseJSON('{"graph_data": {}}');
console.log(typeof(parsedJSON.graph_data));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

no need of `"` for object, `"` is needed for defining string and object key. So it will treat as string here. For more about JSON structure and example visit http://www.json.org/.

Answer (score 0):

try it.

`var parsedJSON = $.parseJSON('{"graph_data": "{}"}');
 console.log(parsedJSON.graph_data);`